# send F5 key to browsers using PostMessage

Tags: c, keypress, postmessage

I loaded "html.html" file in Firefox browser and used the following code to refresh it which works fine.

```c
int main()
{
    HWND v;
    v = FindWindow(NULL, "Mozilla Firefox");
    if (v == NULL)
       print("not found");
    else
    {
         print("found");
         PostMessage(v, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F5, 0);
         PostMessage(v, WM_KEYUP, VK_F5, 0);
    }
}
```

I loaded the same file in Google Chrome browser and modified the window title in the previous code to "html.html - Google Chrome". The code finds the window but the browser is not refreshed. The same (no refresh) happens with Opera and Microsoft Edge.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT 1:**

I used the following to send Ctrl+F5, but I still cannot refresh Chrome.

```c
    PostMessage(v, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_CONTROL, 0);
    PostMessage(v, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F5, 0);
    PostMessage(v, WM_KEYUP, VK_F5, 0);
    PostMessage(v, WM_KEYUP, VK_CONTROL, 0);
```

**EDIT 2:**

*(After being asked about tests with other automation software.)*

I prefer to use pure WinAPI. Also, I already have the right key because F5 is used to refresh those browsers. To prove that, I called `SetForegroundWindow()` before sending the key and it will refresh all browsers.

But I cannot use `SetForegroundWindow()` because I need to keep the browser in the background, also calling this function is just overhead since without it, the code works fine for Firefox.

So what is the difference between Firefox and the others in this specific matter?

Comment: You are trying to emulate a keystroke in those browsers, and the shortcuts for reloading a page may be different among browsers. In MacOS at least, yes you can use `fn-F5` to reload a page in Firefox, but in Chrome you need to use `Command-R`

Comment: @Agus, Just like in Firefox, F5 (and Ctrl-R) does a "soft" refresh Chrome in the relevant OS. (And Ctrl-F5 does a "hard" refresh in both browsers.)

Comment: I used the following to send Ctrl+F5, but I still cannot refresh Chrome. PortMessage(v,WM_KEYDOWN,VK_CONTROL,0);
 PortMessage(v,WM_KEYDOWN,VK_F5,0);
 PortMessage(v,WM_KEYUP,VK_F5,0);
 PortMessage(v,WM_KEYUP,VK_CONTROL,0);

Comment: Did you try other tools like AutoIt3 or AutoHotkey? Just to make sure that you have the right key, and after that try to find the correct algorithm...

Comment: Oh, and don't you mean `PostMessage()` with an 'S'?

Comment: @the busybee. sorry, my mistake, it is Post. ok. I prefer to use pure WinAPI. also, I already have the right key because F5 is used to refresh those browsers. to prove that, call SetForegroundWindow() before sending the key and it will refresh all browsers. but I cannot use SetForegroundWindow() because I need to keep the browser in the background, also calling this function is just overhead since without it, the code works fine for Firefox. so what is the difference between Firefox and the others in this specific matter.

Comment: Perhaps the other browsers take into account whether they have the top window or not, what is a strange thing, but hey. You could download the source code of Chromium (base of Chrome) and try to find something. Or you could ask on their support sites. -- I ask about AutoIt3 because if this tool can do it, you should be able, too. But if AutoIt3 does not trigger a refresh, it might be the wrong key.

Comment: @the busybee, thank you for your reply. I will try to ask on the Chrome support site (I hope I will find their link). I will also try to use the packages you recommended and let you know.